# How to make a pull request to a colleague's branch while being the owner of the repository?

Tags: git, github, workflow

I'm working on a project with a friend from college. I'm the owner of the repo, and he makes a pull request to his branch, while I work on my own feature branch.
Sometimes I'd like to review and suggest changes to his code like he does to my branch with pull requests, but since I'm the owner of the repository, it seems I can only push directly. How do I accomplish this?

Any recommendations about our workflow would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub has a *branch* list just above the files, and clicking on a different branch will let you edit it. Within that branch, you could commit to a different branch and start a Pull Request, as demonstrated here:

[image: Pull Request to branch]

Using git CLI, you could:

1. `git checkout <other-branch>`
2. make some changes
3. `git checkout -b <your-new-branch>`
4. `git add <whatever>`
5. `git commit -m <message>`
6. `git push -u origin <branch>`

and then on GitHub, start a new Pull Request from `<your-new-branch>` to `<other-branch>`.

Comment: So do I need to make a new branch with my suggestions, and then make a pull request from this new branch to my friend's branch?

Comment: @SebastianArrieta Correct. The GitHub PR page lets you compare branches against one another, not just against `master`.